# How to pass mocked data for a GET call, in jest spyOn method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

How to pass a mocked data to GET calls, using jest spyOn method.

I have recently started using jest, for mocking API requests I am using jest spyOn method, I have successfully mocked for post requests, but unable to do it for GET methods

//User flow

1. User clicks a button, which makes two asynchronous calls, and then renders a form, which user fills up and click on submit.

```
//Request.js
export const requestOne = async (id) => {
  const { data }= await axios.get(`fake${id}/request-one`);
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};
export const requestTwo = async (id) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`fake/request-two`);
  return data;
};
export const requestThree = async (data) => {
  await axios.put(`fake/request-three`, data);
  return data;
};
```

```
//test.jsx
import * as requests from './requests';
describe('Test', () => {
 it('should make both get calls on click of button', () => {
// This test is failing
   const spyOne = 
       jest.spyOn(requests, 'requestOne').mockImplementationOnce(() => 
       Promise.resolve(mockedRequestOneDetails));

   const spyTwo = jest.spyOn(requests, 'requestTwo');
         jest.spyOn(requests, 'requestTwo').mockImplementationOnce(() => 
          Promise.resolve(mockedRequestTwoDetails));
   const {  container } = render(<Dom />);

  // Unable to call requestOne and request two mocked data
 })
 it('should make post data to server', () => {
// This test is success
   const spy = jest.spyOn(requests, 'requestThree ');
   const {  container } = render(<Dom />);

   // Fill form details and submit
   await wait(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
 })
});
```

Current Working solution:
For Get calls

axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(mockedDataOne));
axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(mockedDataTwo));

Expected:
Similar to post spyOn method, I should be able to send mocked data, similar to

jest.spyOn(requests, 'requestOne');
Send mocked data to requestOne and requestTwo

Comment: Take a look at [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter), that might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to mock data on GET requests, you can use `jest.mock` instead as shown in [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules):

```js
import Component from "./Component"
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

test('should fetch users', async () => {
  const users = ["Bob", "John", "Jane"]
  const response = {data: users};
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response);

  const { getByText } = render(<Component/>)

  await wait(() => {
    users.forEach(user => getByText(user))
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, But in my case, I don't want to mock whole Axios [jest.mock('Axios')] module, I want to spyOn each method similar to what I am doing on POST requests (spyOn(requests, 'request3') see above).